# How to make a dictionary in python from a text file seperated by paragraph with the key in the first line of each new paragraph?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text-files

I have a text file with the following information:

```
Cake 1  
Cake description 1   
Cake description 2  
Cake description 3

Cake 2  
Cake description (2) 1  
Cake description (2) 2  
Cake description (2) 3

Cake 3   
Cake description (3) 1  
Cake description (3) 2
```

I was wondering how would code this in python to import the text file as a dictionary
with the keys being cake 1, cake 2, cake 3
and the values corresponding to the cakes respectively
i.e

```
cake = { cake 1: ['cake description 1\n', 'cake description 2\n', 'cake description 3\n'], 
         cake 2: ['cake description 2(1)\n', 'cake description 2(2)\n', 'cake description 2(3)\n'], 
         cake 3: ['cake description 3(1)\n', 'cake description 3(2)\n'] }
```

Thanks!

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to split your text on `\n\n` and then split each paragraph individually.

```py
values = []
with open('youfile.txt','r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    for paragraph in text.split('\n\n'):
       tmp = paragraph.split('\n',1)
       key, value = tmp[0], tmp[1]
       values.append({key: value})
```